# Python Pandas cumulative sum of a column plotting

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I have a daily output for a cropping system data frame with multiple outputs from a crop model. I need to take a cumulative of a column (dThrTime) and add the cumulative values in the data frame as a new column. I was able to that but when I am trying to plot the newly added cumulative column against a daily time series, I get an error : ValueError: Could not interpret value `GDU` for parameter `y`

> Blockquote

```
def read_data(file_name, run):
    data_df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    data_df['Date'] = data_df['Date'].apply (lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
    data_df['Year'] = data_df['Date'].apply (lambda x: datetime.strftime(x, '%Y'))
    data_df['run_name'] = run
    return data_df
filenc = "up_goldsboro.csv"
all_df = read_data(filenc, run = "restricted")

#separating data for each crop year 
harvest_2011 = datetime.strptime("2012-05-17",'%Y-%m-%d')
planting_2011 = datetime.strptime("2011-10-27",'%Y-%m-%d')
data_2011 = all_df.loc[all_df["Date"]<=harvest_2011]
data_2011 = data_2011.loc[data_2011["Date"]>=planting_2011]

#Taking cumulative of a column named dThrTime
all_df['GDU'] = all_df['dThrTime'].cumsum(axis = 0, skipna = True)

#Plotting error
sns.lineplot(x = "Date", y = "GDU", data=data_2011)
plt.ylabel("Clover Root Biomass in kg/ha")
plt.title("Location:Goldsboro,NC\n Termination Year: 2012\n Clover GDU")
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJFxu.png)

Comment: isn't GDU in all_df, not data_2011. sns.lineplot(x = "Date", y = "GDU", data=data_2011)

Comment: @JonathanLeon That was a smart catch. I was subsetting the crop year (data_2011) before taking the cumulative. Switched the order and it worked.